# Replace Battery in LEGO Dino Attack Light-Up T-Rex Head?

Tags: repair, electronics, battery, lighting

Is it possible to replace the battery of the LEGO Dino Attack T-Rex head?

[image: T-Rex Head]

There's a button on the top of the head that makes the eyes and tongue light up red, presumably via a red LED.

There doesn't seem to be any obvious way to take it apart like other light-up LEGO elements from the era. Is it possible to disassemble this element and replace the batteries?

Comment: There is one head on Bricklink with empty battery. Maybe there is really no way to replace it? I don't have this head, do you know where exactly the battery is located?

Comment: @Aziraphale I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in the black top piece, but otherwise, no I haven't tried forcing my way into one yet to know where exactly it is.

Comment: I'm tempted to purchase one of these just to see if I can figure it out.  I guess if it breaks we'll have our answer :)

Comment: Look closely at the dino's head. Here you can see little aperture that splits T-rex's upper jaw on half. On this picture I'm showing you what I mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfd4v.jpg I think that's the "ticket" to replace battery without destruction, isn't it? Just use pocket knife to open. Will it work?

Comment: No, but I'm going to buy one set and try.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as sorting out our sons lego and was wanting to replace the batteries. Doesnt seem any way in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately after attacking this piece from every angle with some plastic opening tools, I'm quite certain there is no non-destructive way to open this piece.

I tried slipping a spudger in every seam where the plastic joins and was unable to find anywhere I could get any leverage, or even push it in more than a few millimeters.

Even the jaw piece is held on by a cylinder of plastic running from cheek to cheek. There isn't a good way to photograph it, but here's an illustration to show you what I mean.

[image]

Based on this experience, I believe it is held together by single-use plastic clips that snap into place on the inside without any way to detach them, short of breaking them. I do not think it is glued together, because the two halves do shift a tiny amount under pressure, and some points were much more resistant to inserting a spudger than others (perhaps because a clip is in that area).

Comment: You're dissapointing me! You couldn't wait for expert's answer and you answered yourself!

Comment: Self answering is **encouraged** on the Stack Exchange, information is valuable no matter if original author found it, or someone else. And you should not use "answer" field for criticism. That's what comments are for.